# How do I update MySQL installed with Homebrew on a Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I've installed MySQL on a Mac via `brew`.

I do constant `brew` updates but MySQL keeps telling me it has a new version.

Does `brew update` not update MySQL?

If so then how should I do it? Manually?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No, `brew update` only updates Homebrew itself including retrieving the latest list of formulas/packages available.

Once you have ran `brew update` you can then upgrade all formulas/packages using:

```
brew upgrade
```

To upgrade a particular package you can use the `brew upgrade` command like:

```
brew upgrade mysql
```

Before running an upgrade you may want to know what can be or is going to be upgraded using the command:

```
brew outdated
```

**NOTE** always remember to read the post install/upgrade notes that are output. Some packages require manual steps post install/upgrade like major database version upgrades often require data upgrade/migration procedures to be run.

Comment: So we have to run a specific upgrade for everything installed? And is this valid for cash formulas as well?

Comment: I've already gave you the answer, but I was wondering if you knew if this is the same for cask installs? Say virtualbox for instance

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't comment on cask installs. I only use the core Homebrew tools. I understand that it is an extension to support OS X applications so I presume there must be an equivalent function. Maybe someone else can help? Should that be a _Homebrew Cask_ specific question?

Comment: You may also need to run `mysql_upgrade` after the brew upgrade. Ex: `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.24/bin/mysql_upgrade`